# Python Mongoengine with $nin with pattern

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, mongoengine

I am very new to Mongo engine and currently I have mongo query filter that is working in mongo shell but I wanted to achieve the same in Mongoengine , can you please help me

Mongo Shell Query
`{name:{$nin:[/ja/,/ra/]}}`

but same is not working with Mongoengine

`namelist = NameRecord.objects(name__nin=['/ja/','/ra/'])`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

First of all I would like to thank @tom-slabbaert for pointing me the what was wrong , as he pointed the issue was with regex of python and finally with his input I am able to find the solution, in fact all credits goes to him just I am adding answer so it will be helpful any others in future

`namelist = NameRecord.objects(name__nin=[re.compile(r"ja"), re.compile(r"ra")])`

Answer (score 1):

In the Mongo shell you're using javascript [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) syntax, `/string/` is a regex and not a string. unlike in python where youse using these values are strings.

All you need to do is convert them to the python regex equivalent:

```
namelist = NameRecord.objects(name__nin=[r"ja", r"ra"])
```

Comment: I tried this but for some reason I am getting the expected result :(

Comment: Maybe you can edit in what your getting + the expect result?

Comment: Actually I was expecting to return the records only where name field doesn't contain ja or ra but this is resulting me even with names ja or ra

Comment: Is it by any chance due to case sensitivity?

Comment: no no because all the names are in lower case so it is not related to case sensitivity

Comment: Thanks @Tom I have solved the issue with your inputs :)

Comment: Glad i could help.